# ng-click not returning with modified data from table

Tags: angularjs

My table is as follows:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table table-sm table-inverse table-responsive table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SL No.</th>
            <th>RuleName</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="eachData in ruleEngineData">

            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{eachData.ruleType.ref}}</td>
            <td>{{eachData.ruleType.message}}</td>
            <td>
                <input id="number" type="number" value={{eachData.ruleType.priority}} min="1" max="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="switch">
                    <input ng-if="eachData.active == true" type="checkbox" checked>
                    <input ng-if="eachData.active == false" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button class="submit" ng-click="modifyRuleEngine(ruleEngineData)">Save</button>
    </footer>
</div>
```

The data is displayed correctly:

```
$scope.getRuleEngine = function() {
    var data = {
        orgId: localStorage.getItem('organization_id')
    };
    var config = {
        params: data
    };
    $http.get("/getRuleEngine", config).then(getRuleEngineCallBack, getRuleEngineErrorCallback);
}
```

but when I click save after changing the "Priority" and "Active" data, the modified values are not sent back :

```
$scope.modifyRuleEngine = function(ruleEngineData) {
    var dataModified = {
        orgId: localStorage.getItem('organization_id')
    };
    var configModified = {
        params: data
    };
    $http.get("/modifyRuleEngine", configModified).then(modifyRuleEngineCallBack, modifyRuleEngineErrorCallback);
}
```

The `ruleEngineData` has earlier data in it and not the modified ones.

Comment: Well, how and where do you modify priotity and active? You're only **displaying** the value inside inputs here. You're never binding the input to your model. Learn to use ng-model and forms. Read the documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, it works, I had to add ng-model and a `stringToNumber` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added this directive:

```
app.directive('stringToNumber', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                return '' + value;
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                return parseFloat(value);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and the html to :

```
 <td>
     <input id="number" type="number" string-to-number
            ng-model = "eachData.ruleType.priority"
            value={{eachData.ruleType.priority}} min="1" max="3">
 </td>

 <td>
     <label class="switch">
         <input ng-if="eachData.active == true" type="checkbox" checked
                ng-model = "eachData.active">
         <input ng-if="eachData.active == false" type="checkbox"
                ng-model = "eachData.active">
         <span class="slider round"></span>
     </label>
 </td>
```